# Laravel - How use HasMany

Tags: laravel

I have a little problem with model relationships.

I have a Users table and a Appartaments table, with a hasmany relationship linked from the ref_user field(Users) to the agent field(Appartaments). Neither is a primary key.

In my User model I have:

```
    public function appartaments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Appartament::class,'agent','ref_user');
}
public function idAppartaments($id){
    return User::find($id)->appartaments;
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public function getAppUser($ref_user){
    $id = User::select('id')->where('ref_user',$ref_user)->get();
    $appartaments = User::idAppartaments($id);
    return $appartaments;
```

When I try the route however, I get an error that the appartaments property does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide the table of users and appartements and the appartements model

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to do so:
in your User Model:

```
public function appartaments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Appartament::class,'agent','ref_user');
}
```

in your controller:

```
public function getAppUser($ref_user){
    $user = User::with('appartaments')->where('ref_user',$ref_user)->first();
    $appartaments = $user ? $user->appartaments : null;
    return $appartaments;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `->firstOrFail()`, then you want have to do `$user ? $user->appartaments : null;`. Your code will instead throw a `ModelNotFoundException` if nothing is returned from your query 

Comment: happy to help;
@TimLewis, sure thing, depends on what he wanna do eventually

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your controller method:

```
public function getAppUser($ref_user){
$id = User::select('id')->where('ref_user',$ref_user)->get();
$appartaments = User::idAppartaments($id);
return $appartaments;
```

The method should be:

```
public function getAppUser($ref_user){
$id = User::select('id')->where('ref_user',$ref_user)->get();
$appartaments = $id->appartaments();
return $appartaments;
```

Comment: it doesn't work... BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::appartaments does not exist. in file C:\Users\Stefano\Desktop\Progetto Casa App\Laravel\progettocasa\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 113

Comment: `->first()`, not `->get()`. Get returns them as a Collection, even if there's only 1 record.

Comment: i change ->get() with ->first() and now it says "TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called"

Comment: ok... I changed $id->appartaments() with $id->appartaments and it says not error but return an empty array .. i think it is due to the fact that my local key is not id, but the ref_user field ... but if i write $ref_user->apparataments it says "Trying to get property 'appartaments' of non-object"